# how can I get faster FTS4 query results ordered by a field in another table?

Tags: sqlite, fts3, fts4

**Background**

I'm implementing full-text search over a body of email messages stored in SQLite, making use of its fantastic built-in [FTS4](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) engine.  I'm getting some rather poor query performance, although not exactly where I would expect.  Let's take a look.

**Representative schema**

I'll give some simplified examples of the code in question, with links to the full code where applicable.

We've got a `MessageTable` that stores the data about an email message (full version spread out over several files [here](http://git.yorba.org/cgit.cgi/geary/tree/sql/version-001.sql), [here](http://git.yorba.org/cgit.cgi/geary/tree/sql/version-004.sql), and [here](http://git.yorba.org/cgit.cgi/geary/tree/sql/version-012.sql)):

```
CREATE TABLE MessageTable (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    internaldate_time_t INTEGER
);
CREATE INDEX MessageTableInternalDateTimeTIndex
    ON MessageTable(internaldate_time_t);
```

The searchable text is added to an FTS4 table named `MessageSearchTable` (full version [here](http://git.yorba.org/cgit.cgi/geary/tree/src/engine/imap-db/imap-db-database.vala#n106)):

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE MessageSearchTable USING fts4(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    body
);
```

The `id` in the search table acts as a foreign key to the message table.

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to insert data into these tables (I certainly can't give out my private email).  I have just under 26k records in each table.

**Problem query**

When we retrieve search results, we need them to be ordered descending by `internaldate_time_t` so we can pluck out only the most recent few results.  Here's an example search query (full version [here](http://git.yorba.org/cgit.cgi/geary/tree/src/engine/imap-db/imap-db-account.vala#n644)):

```
SELECT id
FROM MessageSearchTable
JOIN MessageTable USING (id)
WHERE MessageSearchTable MATCH 'a'
ORDER BY internaldate_time_t DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

On my machine, with my email, that runs in about 150 milliseconds, as measured via:

```
time sqlite3 test.db <<<"..." > /dev/null
```

150 milliseconds is no beast of a query, but for a simple FTS lookup and indexed order, it's sluggish.  If I omit the `ORDER BY`, it completes in 10 milliseconds, for example.  Also keep in mind that the actual query has one more sub-select, so there's a little more work going on in general: the full version of the query runs in about 600 milliseconds, which is into beast territory, and omitting the `ORDER BY` in that case shaves 500 milliseconds off the time.

If I turn on stats inside `sqlite3` and run the query, I notice the line:

```
Sort Operations:                     1
```

If my interpretation of the [docs about those stats](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_stmtstatus_counter.html) is correct, it looks like the query is completely skipping using the `MessageTableInternalDateTimeTIndex`.  The full version of the query also has the line:

```
Fullscan Steps:                      25824
```

Sounds like it's walking the table somewhere, but let's ignore that for now.

**What I've discovered**

So let's work on optimizing that a little bit.  I can rearrange the query into a sub-select and force SQLite to use our index with the [`INDEXED BY`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_indexedby.html) extension:

```
SELECT id
FROM MessageTable
INDEXED BY MessageTableInternalDateTimeTIndex
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM MessageSearchTable
    WHERE MessageSearchTable MATCH 'a'
)
ORDER BY internaldate_time_t DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Lo and behold, the running time has dropped to around 100 milliseconds (300 milliseconds in the full version of the query, a 50% reduction in running time), and there are no sort operations reported.  Note that with just reorganizing the query like this but not forcing the index with `INDEXED BY`, there's still a sort operation (though we've still shaved off a few milliseconds oddly enough), so it appears that SQLite is indeed ignoring our index unless we force it.

I've also tried some other things to see if they'd make a difference, but they didn't:

- Explicitly making the index `DESC` as described [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html), with and without `INDEXED BY`
- Explicitly adding the `id` column in the index, with and without `internaldate_time_t` ordered `DESC`, with and without `INDEXED BY`
- Probably several other things I can't remember at this moment

**Questions**

100 milliseconds here still seems awfully slow for what seems like it should be a simple FTS lookup and indexed order.

- What's going on here?  Why is it ignoring the obvious index unless you force its hand?
- Am I hitting some limitation with combining data from virtual and regular tables?
- Why is it still so relatively slow, and is there anything else I can do to get FTS matches ordered by a field in another table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An index is useful for looking up a table row based on the value of the indexed column.
Once a table row is found, indexes are no longer useful because it is not efficient to look up a table row in an index by any other criterium.

An implication of this is that **it is not possible to use more than one index for each table accessed in a query**.

Also see the documentation: [Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html), [Query Optimizer](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html).

---

Your first query has the following [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output:

```
0 0 0 SCAN TABLE MessageSearchTable VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 4: (~0 rows)
0 1 1 SEARCH TABLE MessageTable USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)
0 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

What happens is that

1. the FTS index is used to find all matching `MessageSearchTable` rows;
2. for each row found in 1., the `MessageTable` primary key index is used to find the matching row;
3. all rows found in 2. are sorted with a temporary table;
4. the first 10 rows are returned.

Your second query has the following EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output:

```
0 0 0 SCAN TABLE MessageTable USING COVERING INDEX MessageTableInternalDateTimeTIndex (~100000 rows)
0 0 0 EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
1 0 0 SCAN TABLE MessageSearchTable VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 4: (~0 rows)
```

What happens is that

1. the FTS index is used to find all matching `MessageSearchTable` rows;
2. SQLite goes through all entries in the `MessageTableInternalDateTimeTIndex` in the index order, and returns a row when the `id` value is one of the values found in step 1.
   SQLite stops after the tenth such row.

In this query, it is possible to use the index for (implied) sorting, but only because no other index is used for looking up rows in this table.
Using an index in this way implies that SQLite has to go through *all* entries, instead of lookup up the few rows that match some other condition.

When you omit the `INDEXED BY` clause from your second query, you get the following EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output:

```
0 0 0 SEARCH TABLE MessageTable USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~25 rows)
0 0 0 EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
1 0 0 SCAN TABLE MessageSearchTable VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 4: (~0 rows)
0 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

which is essentially the same as your first query, except that joins and subqueries are handled slightly differently.

---

With your table structure, it is not really possible to get faster.
You are doing three operations:

1. looking up rows in `MessageSearchTable`;
2. looking up corresponding rows in `MessageTable`;
3. sorting rows by a `MessageTable` value.

As far as indexes are concerned, steps 2 and 3 conflict with each other.
The database has to choose whether to use an index for step 2 (in which case sorting must be done explicitly) or for step 3 (in which case it has to go through all `MessageTable` entries).

You could try to return fewer records from the FTS search by making the message time a part of the FTS table and searching only for the last few days (and increasing or dropping the time if you don't get enough results).

Comment: "it is not possible to use more than one index for each table accessed in a query" - that's not _technically_ true; see the end of [this section](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html#section_1_1), although I'll concede that internally it's executing two separate queries and `UNION`-ing the results.

Comment: "You are doing three operations: looking up rows in MessageSearchTable;..." - the goal would be not to look up _rows_ at all, just primary keys.  It seems that any index should be considered a covering index (see the relevant sections in the query [planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) and [optimization](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) docs), and thus _all_ table scans should be able to be avoided.

Comment: "making the message time a part of the FTS table" - my understanding of FTS tables is that it's not possible to add any arbitrary data, just text indexed by the FTS algorithm.  Is that wrong?  How would I be able to add the column to the FTS table and be able to order on it?

Comment: The above are just some questions and notes that came up with your excellent answer.  I wasn't aware of `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`; I'd just been using `EXPLAIN SELECT...` which is _much_ harder to follow.  Anyway, thanks for your answer!  I'd like to give it a few more days before accepting it to see if anyone else can shed any insight here.

Comment: Having a covering index does not change the fact that you cannot use another index for that table. In FTS tables, you can use multiple columns and store numbers in them. FTS tables cannot have normal indexes (so no optimized `ORDER BY`), but you can do a full-text-search for these values (they are just indexed as text). The purpose of searching for the time is just to reduce the number of records that need to be processed afterwards.